# Ember.js - default template to render into an outlet?

Tags: ember.js

So I have a page which looks like the following

```
[ Nav Bar ]

|         |
| Content |
|         |
```

The nav bar I want to be constant across all pages. So the approach I used was to set my page up as follows:

```
[ Nav Bar ]

{{outlet}}
```

This is great, I can now render different pages into my outlet for different routes.

But what if I want a default template to be rendered into the outlet for my home page?

I've managed to achieve this by redirecting `/` to `/home`, but there must be a better way to do this which allows me to render a default home page at `/` without re-routing?

Any advice appreciated,

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To render stuff in the {{outlet}} at the root page /, you have to define a handlerbar script for index:

Your navbar code probably look like this:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  <div class="navbar ...">
    ...
  </div>

  {{outlet}}
</script>
```

The root page that will be place inside {{outlet}} is the fallowing:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Root page!!</h1>
    </div>
</script>
```

**In other words, you have to create a handlebar script that will have an id="index".**

Should work. It doesn't need any js code to work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I already have an 'index' template -- that's the template which contains the nav bar and the outlet...

Comment: Then you should only have to move the navbar inside the handlebars that doesn't have any id or data-template-name. Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/jorat1346/8tvRj/1/
You have content at the home page, why this model wouldn't work.

Comment: Right -- my difficulty with what you're suggesting was, I have a model I needed to use to populate the navbar, but since the router doesn't seem to be invoked for the application (only the 'index'), I had nowhere to populate my model.

Thinking about it though, I figure I can get around this by creating MyApp.ApplicationController, and populating my model in init().

Thanks for all the advice, will try some of this out.

Answer (score 1):

I must admit this property is not well documented and buried in the docs for [`Ember.View`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html) but you could try setting the `defaultTemplate` property on your `ApplicationView`. See [here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html) for more info on that (search in the page for 'defaultTemplate').

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Ended up going with the above answer, but this was also helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The following statement in docs helped me to solve exactly the same problem I was having which is stated in the question:
[Ember routing docs](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.7.0/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_index-routes)

> The index template will be rendered into the {{outlet}} in the application template. If the user navigates to /favorites, Ember will replace the index template with the favorites template.

As I am using pod structure in my project, I created an index route having my default template and I placed nav-bar component in my application/template.hbs file.

**app/application/template.hbs:**

```
<div id="pageWrapper">
    <div id="navbarfixed">{{nav-bar options=options}}</div>
    <div id="pageContent">
        {{outlet}}
    </div>
</div>
```

**app/index/template.hbs**

```
<div id="homeWrapper"> <!--This gets rendered by default in outlet above-->
Some default content of outlet
</div>
```